# Why does my ceiling fan turn off after 20min?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

This fan has a remote, but no light.

The remote has a bunch of buttons that do not seem to help (e.g 1H 2H 8H).

The fan just runs for 20 min then shuts off on its own. I have to press the remote again to start it up again.

Also, I noticed times where the fan would slow for a bit (it actually just turns off for a bit), then after a couple seconds, it would get back back to full speed.

EDIT:
here is a link to the fan: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B09DGFCX76/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

It is brand new and just installed, and there is no light.

Also the fan speed buttons on the remote do not change the fan speed at all. There are 3 other buttons that do not seem to do anything and the translation is pretty rough in the instructions!

Comment: Can you add a photo of remote, or fan, or both?

Comment: Might be a thermal reset, or a sleep timer.  Change of speed might tend to motor problem.

Comment: What make and model of ceiling fan is it?

Comment: How old is it? When it slows do the lights dim, if not it may be the fan motor lubrication has failed, they do this after a lot of use.

Comment: No UL listing, sold by "dandan88", ships from China. Probably not the safest thing to install in your house.

Comment: Are you wedded at the hip to that specific ceiling fan?

Comment: I am not wedded to the fan, but if there was something simple I could do to fix it, I would choose that over returning it and ordering a different one.

Comment: @Michael -- I'd suggest junking it and going to a local electrical or lighting supply to get a replacement